# Reshaping a table

Tags: stata, reshape

I want to `reshape` the following long table:

```
| firm  | data      | average   |
|------ |---------  |---------  |
| A     | workers   | 250       |
| A     | age       | 36.5      |
| A     | salary    | 86180     |
| B     | workers   | 210       |
| B     | age       | 37.5      |
| B     | salary    | 89120     |
| C     | workers   | 100       |
| C     | age       | 27.5      |
| C     | salary    | 98720     |
```

What I want is a wide table like this:

```
| firm  | workers   | age       |salary     |
|------ |---------  |---------  |---------- |
| A     | 250       | 36.5      |86180      |
| B     | 210       | 37.5      |89120      |
| C     | 100       | 27.5      |98720      |
```

I tried `reshape wide average, i(firm) j(data)` but that did not work.
I then tried `reshape wide average, i(firm) j(data) string` and it did not work either.
I then encoded `firm` using `encode firm, gen (name)` and ran `reshape wide average, i(name) j(data)` which did not work either.

Comment: Please see the Stata tag wiki for advice on data examples. Yours is helpful but would be more helpful without the scaffolding.

Comment: `encode` doesn't help here. Otherwise you were close but just needed a `rename` to follow.

Answer (score 2):

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input str7 firm str11 data double average
"A" "workers"   250
"A" "age"      36.5
"A" "salary"  86180
"B" "workers"   210
"B" "age"      37.5
"B" "salary"  89120
"C" "workers"   100
"C" "age"      27.5
"C" "salary"  98720
end

reshape wide average , i(firm) j(data) string 
rename average* * 
list 

     +--------------------------------+
     | firm    age   salary   workers |
     |--------------------------------|
  1. |    A   36.5    86180       250 |
  2. |    B   37.5    89120       210 |
  3. |    C   27.5    98720       100 |
     +--------------------------------+
```